# Can't seem to figure out how to correctly export data to excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
from Functions import *
import xlsxwriter
if __name__ == "__main__" :    
    resposta1= resposta2= nome_utilizador= numero1= numero2= resultadoex2= nota1= nota2= nota3=media_notas= altura= largura= area_retangulo= preco= valordado= troco= distancia= velocidade=tempo_de_viagem= combustivel_gasto= distancia2= Consumo= preco_restaurante= quantidade_pessoas=precopp= golos_totais= jogos_totais= resultado= preco_original= desconto= seguidores_atuais=seguidores_antigos= altura_utilizador= peso= data= capital_inicial= taxa_de_juros= tempo_anos=quantia_euros= taxa_conversao = '0'
    resposta1 = 'a'
    resposta2 = 'a'
    while resposta1 != 'x':
        resposta2 = 'a'
        print(f'-------Menu-------')
        print(f'->1 Compêndio 1')
        print(f'->2 Compêndio 2/3')
        print(f'->x Sair')
        print(f'------------------')
        resposta2 = 'a'
        resposta1 = input('')
        match resposta1:
            case "1":
                while resposta2 != '0':
                    print(f'-------Menu Compêndio 1-------\n')
                    print(f'->1 "Olá utilizador"')
                    print(f'->2 "Aritmia"')
                    print(f'->3 "Média"')
                    print(f'->4 "Área retangulo"')
                    print(f'->5 "Troco"')
                    print(f'->6 "Tempo de viagem"')
                    print(f'->7 "Consumo de combustivel"')
                    print(f'->8 Preco pp')
                    print(f'->0 Voltar') 
                    print(f'->x Sair')
                    print(f'------------------------------')
                    resposta2 = input('')
                    if resposta2 == 'x':
                        resposta1 = 'x'
                        resposta2 = '0'
                    match resposta2:
                    
                        case "1":
                            nome_utilizador = ex1()##ex1
                        case "2":
                            numero1 = int(input('Insira um número: '))
                            numero2 = int(input('Insira outro numero: '))
                            resultadoex2 = ex2(numero1,numero2)

                        case "3":
                            nota1= int(input('Insira as suas notas:\n'))
                            nota2= int(input(''))
                            nota3= int(input(''))
                            media_notas= ex3(nota1,nota2,nota3)
                        case "4":
                            altura = float(input('Insira a altura: '))
                            largura = float(input('Insira a largura: '))
                            area_retangulo = ex4(altura,largura)
                        case "5":
                            preco = float(input('Insira o preco do produto:\n'))
                            valordado = float(input('Insira o valor:\n'))
                            troco = ex5(preco,valordado)
                        case "6":
                            distancia = float(input('Insira a distancia da viagem em km\n'))
                            velocidade = float(input('Insira a velocidade média em km/h\n'))
                            tempo_de_viagem = ex6(distancia,velocidade)
                        case "7":
                            combustivel_gasto = float(input('Insira o combustivel gastoem litros \n'))
                            distancia2 = float(input('Insira a distancia percorrida em km\n'))
                            Consumo = ex7(combustivel_gasto,distancia2)
                        case "8":
                            preco_restaurante = float(input('Insira o preco da refeição\n'))
                            quantidade_pessoas = int(input('Insira a quantidade de pessoas\n'))
                            precopp = ex8(preco_restaurante,quantidade_pessoas)
            case "2":
                while resposta2 != "0":
                    print(f'------Menu Compêndio 2/3------\n')
                    print(f'->1 "Golos por jogo"')
                    print(f'->2 "Preço com desconto"')
                    print(f'->3 "Crescimento de seguidores"')
                    print(f'->4 "IMC"')
                    print(f'->5 "Dias vividos"')
                    print(f'->6 "Juros Simples"')
                    print(f'->7 "Conversão para dolar"')
                    print(f'->0 Voltar') 
                    print(f'->x Sair')
                    print(f'------------------------------')
                    resposta2 = input('')
                    if resposta2 == 'x':
                        resposta1 = 'x'
                        resposta2 = '0'
                    match resposta2:
                        case "1":
                            golos_totais = int(input('Insira a quantidade de golos marcados\n'))
                            jogos_totais = int(input('Insira a quantidade de jogos jogados\n'))
                            resultado = ex9(golos_totais,jogos_totais)
                        case "2":
                            preco_original = float(input('Insira o preco original\n'))
                            desconto = int(input('Insira o desconto\n'))
                            resultado = ex10(preco_original,desconto)
                        case "3":
                            seguidores_atuais = int(input('Insira a quantidade de seguidores que tem\n'))
                            seguidores_antigos = int(input('Insira a quantidade de seguidores que tinha há um mês atrás\n'))
                            resultado = ex11(seguidores_atuais,seguidores_antigos)
                        case "4":
                            altura_utilizador = float(input('Insira a sua altura\n'))
                            peso = float(input('Insira o seu peso\n'))
                            resultado = ex12(peso,altura_utilizador)
                        case "5":
                            data = input("Indique a sua data de nascimento dd/mm/aaaa\n")
                            resultado = ex13(data)
                        case "6":
                            capital_inicial = float(input('Insira a capital inicial\n'))
                            taxa_de_juros = float(input('Insira a taxa de juros\n'))
                            tempo_anos = int(input('Insira a quantidade de anos\n'))
                            resultado = ex14(capital_inicial,taxa_de_juros,tempo_anos)
                        case "7":
                            quantia_euros = float(input('Insira a quantidade em euros\n'))
                            taxa_conversao = float(input('Insira a taxa de conversao para dolar\n'))
                            resultado = ex15(quantia_euros,taxa_conversao)
    data =    [nome_utilizador,nome_utilizador,'','',nome_utilizador],
    [nome_utilizador,numero1,numero2,'',resultadoex2],
    [nome_utilizador,nota1,nota2,nota3,media_notas],
    [nome_utilizador,altura,largura,'',area_retangulo],
    [nome_utilizador,preco,valordado,'',troco],
    [nome_utilizador,distancia,velocidade,'',tempo_de_viagem],
    [nome_utilizador,combustivel_gasto,distancia2,'',Consumo],
    [nome_utilizador,preco_restaurante,quantidade_pessoas,'',precopp]
    index = ['C1E1', 'C1E2', 'C1E3', 'C1E4', 'C1E5', 'C1E6', 'C1E7', 'C1E8']
    columns = ['Nome', 'Input 1', 'Input 2', 'Input 3', 'Output']
    df = DataFrame(data, columns=columns, index=index)
    writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True)
    writer.close()
```

I've been trying all sorts of things on this code now, and i still cant get it to write to excel, when i fill the data i get met with an excel file that only displays this

```
   A     B       C      D      E 
1 Nome Input1 Input2 Input 3 Output
```

With no data filled out, anyone knows what's up? All help and criticism greatly appreciated.

I was hoping to get something of the sort

```
      A        B          C          D        E
  1  Nome    Input1     Input2     Input3   Output
C1E1 ---
C1E2 (name) (numeber1) (number2)  (empty)  (result)
```

Comment: First of all, you need to create a `DataFrame` using pandas. Then, you can call the [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method on the data frame object. I would get rid of the nested while loops and the switch statements. Instead of it, use a `DataFrame` with well-defined column types.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments. Especially `print(df)`. It is called `prind debuging` and it helps to see what code is doing and what you really have in variables. It seems your `data` is empty and it has nothing to write in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a `DataFrame` with the data you have to export.

   `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
2. Then you have to use the to_excel method of your `DataFrame` to export the data to an Excel file.

   `df.to_excel('my_data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet 1', index=False)`

PS. I prefer to set my index to false in order not to include the row numbers as an additional column on the File, but it is still up to you.